# How to make a an array of mutable strings

Tags: swift

Im instantiating a mutable array, but it seems the elements become immutable so that I cant pass references to them to my function.

**ERROR: "Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'word' is a 'let' constant"**

```
// MARK: - Properties

var wordsToTest = ["hannah", "bam"]

// MARK: -  Life cycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for word in wordsToTest {
        print("\(word) is a palindrome - ", isPalindrome(&word))
    }
}
```

How can I go about and fix it?

Comment: The real problem is the `isPalindrome` function. There is no reason why it should take an `inout` parameter. Change that function and don't worry about array being a constant.

Comment: Thanks. I have already solved the problem that way, and Im experimenting with different solutions for fun. isPalindrome is recursive and I did this to see if i could avoid instantiating new strings for each call. And this made me realize that i wouldnt modify the elements directly even if the array was a 'var'. And I wanted to learn more about it. So there is a reason, however how silly :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `var` in `for` `loop`:

```
for var word in wordsToTest //Here
{
    print("\(word) is a palindrome - ", isPalindrome(&word))
}
```

Comment: Nice! So this makes a new variable for every iteration of the loop right? Is there a way to modify the String elements of the array directly? Without having to instantiate new?  Im wondering if i can avoid instantiating new strings ( just out of curiousity, as this sort of thing slowed one of my algorithms down on hackerrank! :) )

Comment: The elements you get from array are let elements. In order to modify them you need to make them mutable and hence  var needs to be used.